# Git prevent direct commit to checked out repo

Tags: git

I have the following situation: I'm sharing a Git repository of scripts for handling a specific dataset via a shared filesystem that also hosts the data. The repo is checked out (not bare) so they can be easily run and the files are writable, so others with access to the shared filesystem (trusted users) can update them. The workflow for updating is

1. clone to homedir,
2. commit changes,
3. pull from homedir into shared repo (because pushing to a checked out repo doesn't change the checked out code).

Now I want to enforce this policy and prevent direct commits to the repository. I know this cannot be done in a watertight way, because the files have to be writable, but I at least want to replace `git commit` with a message saying "don't commit directly, see `README`". How do I do that? I tried

```
git config alias.commit invalid-command-see-README
```

but that didn't change `git commit` behavior at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to rethink your workflow. You said that you would pull into the shared repository *because pushing to a checked out repo doesn't change the checked out code*. This is not entirely true. You can write a *post-recieve* hook which does exactly that.

Furthermore you could write a *pre-commit* hook which forbids direct commits.

Take a look at [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to get a better understanding of what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The pre-commit hook can modify or reject commits.

```
echo 'echo Commits to this repository are disabled. Please push or pull changes from yours instead.; exit 1' > .git/hooks/pre-commit
chmod +x !$
```

(edit: "or pull")

[Zeeker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27295384/1290731) is better than mine. Go accept that one.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried
>
> git config alias.commit invalid-command-see-README

This isn't going to work.  Most of the git commands are themselves shell scripts, and any of them that rely on `git commit` would be broken.  From the `git config` help pages

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide
>   existing git commands are ignored.

I think you would be better off by splitting your your repo in half and having the repository separate from the published scripts.  You could then lock down the repo entirely (via hooks you write yourself of `gitolite`), and as part of the update scripts you could publish the scripts to a shared location.

There are no good solutions that leave users going to the repo to pull changes but not be able to commit.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html). With gitolite you can configure permissions per user. So you could give the users that should not be able to commit only the READ permission.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: suggest pre-commit to block local commit*

How about:

- a pre-commit hook to abort local commits by always returning an error result (non-zero status)
- a pre-receive hook to abort incoming pushes by always returning an error result (non-zero status)

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/

> Pre-Commit
>
> The pre-commit script is executed every time you run git commit before Git asks the developer for a commit message or generates a commit object.
>
> ...
>
> Pre-Receive
>
> The pre-receive hook is executed every time somebody uses
> git push to push commits to the repository. It should always reside in
> the remote repository that is the destination of the push, not in the
> originating repository.

Comment: Pushes are not the problem. Commits (other than pulls) in the checked out repo are.

Comment: @larsmans - Ah, I misunderstood - I was thinking you want to ensure changes are always pulled, not pushed. But I would think a incoming push may circumvent your workflow policy as well. Maybe you would want to block both local commit and incoming push?